# Django allauth - Add custom logic after email verification is successful

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am creating an application that has a list of `Employees`, and after a user registers and verifies their email, I create a relationship between the `Employee` and their `User` account.

I am using Django all auth, and have the email confirmation on `GET` set to True.

I am unsure on how I can add logic, so after the `GET` I perform some operations, find use the email to find the user, etc.

I have created a custom `RegisterSerializer` before, but since this is a `GET` instead of `POST` I wasn't sure if I could do something similar with EmailVerification.

How would I go about adding custom logic for this?

Comment: Did you found anything? I've created similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63133088/7986808

Comment: @khashashin I did yes, I posted an answer to your question.