# Change django-allauth email verification behaivior

Tags: django, django-allauth

Django has builtin User model `is_active` [field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active). I assume that django-allauth sets this field to True after successful e-mail verification.

I would manually enable the user and change this field to "true" via the Django admin interface instead.
Is it possible to change this behavior from django-allauth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is_active` is, like you mentioned, used to determine whether its an active account, and can be flipped to `False` instead of deleting the acccount. But I don't think all-auth does anything with this value, it is automatically set to `True` when you create a `User` object.

What you are looking for is in a separate table, usually "email_addresses". This will show which email addresses have been verified.

Comment: So, theoretically to prevent the user to login, I could use `allauth.account.signals.email_confirmed(request, email_address)` signal and set the user `is_active=False`. In this case I can be sure that this email is confirmed and in the same time prevent them to login and manage this process manually, right?

Comment: Yes you could... but I am a little confused, why would you want to deactivate their account right after they confirmed it? I don't think they would be able to log in after.

Comment: Because it's b2b application and after some organisation creates an account on the application I could manually activate them and send E-mail that they now can use the application.